# JS function not triggered with PrimeFaces.monitorDownload

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working in file downloading with **Primefaces 4.0**. I just want to trigger a JS function when download completes, but seems not to work (tried in Firefox and Google Chrome). My test case looks similar to what's done in the [PF docs](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml):

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />

<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startMessage() {
            alert("Download started!");
        }
        function finishMessage() {
            alert("Download finished!");
        }
    </script>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false"
            icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s"
            onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startMessage, finishMessage)">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.file}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
    }

}
```

The alert is triggered when download starts, but not when download finishes. Could anyone else give it a try?

Comment: Same here, I'm getting recursive javascript errors
`Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,b3){return new bI.fn.init(e,b3,w)} has no method 'cookie' ` , it's a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3806).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it's a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3806).

The main bug is in `FileDownloadActionListener` of `org.primefaces.component.filedownload` package.

Line 65

```
externalContext.addResponseCookie(Constants.DOWNLOAD_COOKIE, "true", Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
```

The `Constants.DOWNLOAD_COOKIE` is "primefaces.download", and it's never sent with the response.

That would cause `PrimeFaces.monitorDownload`'s Interval to never call the stop function, since the cookie is never written.

Comment: If you need to download with a custom solution you need to make this also in your custom download action.

Comment: Right, it´s a bug, does anyone know how to fix it? I am using Primefaces 6 and I can´t upgrade it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found it was related to the ***'path'*** attribute of the cookie created.

My app context path has the form ***'http://host/a/b/c'***, hence in the server the cookie is created with ***'default'*** path as ***'/a/b/c'***, but in the browser I found the cookies retrieved during the JavaScript execution were only the ones with path ***'/a'*** (Chrome) or ***'/a/'*** (Firefox). So even when the ***'primefaces.download'*** cookie was being created, the JavaScript in the client was not retrieving it for the application.

All I had to do was to *'override'* the cookie creation before the response is sent (i.e. create a second cookie with correct path expected by the browser):

```
   ...
   FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
   Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   map.put("path", "/a/");
   externalContext.addResponseCookie(Constants.DOWNLOAD_COOKIE, "true", map);
   ...
```

Also, I noticed the default implementation of **`PrimeFaces.monitorDownload()`** tries to *'clean'* the ***'primefaces.download'*** cookie by just setting its value to **'null'**, but since there is difference in how Chrome and Firefox handle cookies (appending a last *'/'* character to the current path in Firefox) I better did *'override'* also the JS code to clean the cookie once the ending function is executed:

```
   ...    
   document.cookie = 'primefaces.download=; path=/a/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC';
   ...
```

That way I make sure that in the next execution the cookie won't yet be there at all in the client until it again gets created in the server.

Comment: Haven't tested it, but seems as a smart workaround ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for me. I had to set the file path as well. I am using PrimeFaces 6.1

Comment: Thanks for the comment Xtreme Biker :)

Comment: Those are great news wolf97084, it's good to know it worked for you too