# Replacing a button with another under primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

EDITED

I would like to replace a button by another in Primefaces

I have a checkout part , which downloads a file and then, after the download, must be replaced with a checkin button which can upload a file. Ater the upload, the checkin button transforms back into a checkout button.

WARNING I think the problem may be related to

[JS function not triggered with PrimeFaces.monitorDownload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663551/js-function-not-triggered-with-primefaces-monitordownload)

I have 2 problems:

1)  I have to refresh the browser manually after clicking  on the download button so that it transforms into a upload button

2) I don't know how to invoke the method that transforms the upload button back into the upload button

the XHTML code is:

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel">

<p:panel id="checkoutPanel" rendered="#{myBean.checkout}" >

<p:commandButton value="Checkout" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop) update="panel" actionListener="#{myBean.checkinTurn}">
  <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.downloadFile(myBean.File)}" actionListener="#{editUDBean.checkinTurn}"/>  
   </p:commandButton> 
  </p:panel>

<p:remoteCommand name="stop" update="checkinPanel">   
</p:remoteCommand>

 <p:panel id="checkinPanel" rendered="#{editUDBean.checkin}">
     <h:outputLabel value="Checkin"/>
     <h:outputLabel value="#{editUDBean.checkin}"/>

   <p:fileUpload label="Checkin"  fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml|XML)$/" auto="true"  />
     </p:panel>
 </h:panelGrid>


 @ManagedBean(name="fileDownloadController", eager = true)
 @SessionScoped
 public class FileDownloadController implements Serializable{

    private boolean checkout = false; 

    public boolean isCheckout() {
    return checkout;
   }

   public void setCheckout(boolean checkout) {
    this.checkout = checkout;
   }

   public StreamedContent downloadFile(File file) {

    checkout = true;
    ...
  }

}
```

Any hints ?

Comment: can you try updating checkoutpanel?

Comment: I am afraid you can't do it. filedownload MUST be non-ajax and update must be ajax. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744778/update-component-after-file-download

Comment: I have made some changes according to advice given into the link, I just ot click once, but I have to update the browser manually so that it works OK