# primefaces.download response cookie not set in browser

Tags: cookies, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm trying so setup file Download for primefaces as described here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml

**Primefaces** version **6**.

There is a cookie called primefaces.download that needs to be set during the download process, in order to monitor the download process using javascript.

The response header has these cookie set as you can see bellow:

```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
   X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0
   X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
   X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
   X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
   X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
   X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
   Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="aggregatedContent"
   Set-Cookie: primefaces.download=true
   Content-Type: text/plain
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Date: Tue, 11 Jul 2017 05:42:41 GMT
```

But when I look in Chrome in the Application->Cookies, this cookie is not there.This is true for Firefox and Internet explorer as well.
 Also, typing in console document.cookie does not return this set cookie.

P.S. The request is a POST with status 200 returned from a request URL on localhost.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your PF version ?

Comment: I forgot the mention that. I use Primefaces 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS function not triggered with PrimeFaces.monitorDownload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663551/js-function-not-triggered-with-primefaces-monitordownload)

Comment: Have a look at comment #10 https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/issues/3806

Comment: I had a look at those links. For me the onClick method is called and it show the loading gif, then once the reply is received with the payload, I also receive in the response header this :Set-Cookie: primefaces.download=true. But JS cannot read it, I tried it myself to read it from the debug console and indeed you cannot read it. This puzzles me as it should be there but it just not.